# check email if valid/duplicate from database using codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, email

i have a code from tutorial that doesn't work well. I don't know why, i am a beginner in codeigniter. I want to submit the button update, if duplicate a text will response below the textbox that the email is exist and also check it if the email is a valid email syntax.

Here is my html code :

```
<form id="reg_form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="curEmail">New Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="youremail@yourcompany.com" required data-fv-emailaddress-message="The value is not a valid email address">                                                           
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 ajax_response_result"></div>                                                       
    </div>
    <button onclick="editEmail()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

Here is my ajax:

```
function editEmail() {

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('manager/profile/check_email') ?>",    
    data: $("#reg_form").serialize(),
    success: function(res) {
     $(".ajax_response_result").html(res);

     }
    });

}
```

My CodeIgniter Controller:

```
public function check_email() {
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[user.user_email]|valid_email');

         $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The %s is already taken');
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE):
                echo 'Enter valid email.';          
        else :           
            unset($_POST);
            echo 'Available';
        endif;

  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. I think for unique it is from database. if it is exist. but it doesnt work well.

Comment: did u load `$this->load->library('form_validation');` ?

Comment: yes sir. i already did. there are no errors sir. but the code behaves nothing.

Comment: already loaded. URL,form_validation,etc.

Comment: there are so many example here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: all i want sir is to check wether it is existing or not. the most important

Comment: valid_email and required is working fine here?

Comment: why is it when i click the button, it refresh sir ? or something it loads back? i used ajax then why is it refreshed?

Comment: yes, after this `success: function(res) {
     $(".ajax_response_result").html(res);

     }
    });` add `return false;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125158/discussion-between-devpro-and-jc-john).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issue in your code, Revised & given below

HTML (method `POST` was not there in your code, editEmail here `event` missing etc etc)

```
<form id="reg_form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="curEmail">New Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="youremail@yourcompany.com" required data-fv-emailaddress-message="The value is not a valid email address">                                                           
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 ajax_response_result"></div>                                                       
    </div>
    <button onclick="editEmail(event)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

Now JS (`e.preventDefault();` used for prevent form submitting etc etc)

```
function editEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('manager/profile/check_email') ?>",    
    data: $("#reg_form").serialize(),
    success: function(res) {
     $(".ajax_response_result").html(res);

     }
    });

}
```

Comment: @hey sir. very great answer sir. thanks for editting my code. it helps me very well. thank you very much sir.

Comment: @JcJohn enjoy your day

Comment: hello sir. may i ask again ? why is my error message from 
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The %s is already taken'); is not working ?

Comment: to get validation error all you have to do is use `echo strip_tags(validation_errors())` instead `echo 'Enter valid email.';` in controller

Comment: @RejoanulAlam sir, i mean the set_message error for every  rules of form_validation